# Batch file has errors when run, but enter trough command line works fine

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm helping one of my friends with his QA work. A lot of the time ctfmon.exe is always running in the background and he says it takes up memory on the computer for when he's testing. My friends work machine is using Windows XP

He already tried what was said in this article but it didn't help.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-ctfmonexe-and-why-is-it-running/

We then tried to create a simple batch file that would stop the process for him.
Here are the two files that we have

**delete_cftmon.reg:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"ctfmon.exe"=
```

**Novoice.bat**

```
taskkill /F /IM ctfmon.exe /T
regedit.exe /s delete_cftmon.reg
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run C:\WINDOWS\system32\ctfmon.exe
rem reg delete [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run] "ctfmon.exe"
```

I get the following errors "*invalid command line parameters*" and "*Invalid key name"*

When we enter the commands via the command line it works fine.

I believe it has to do with HKEY_CURRENT_USER but I'm not entirely sure why.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the reg command take out the `[` and `]` and replace them both with " " and you can use `HKCU` for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` - type `reg /?` for help with the other reg switches.  Also, in the .reg file a minus sign is used to remove a key.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q282599 <-- there is info on cftmon and how to remove it.